# Jenkins is generating excessive keys in Keychain Access on MacOS Node

Tags: jenkins, keychain, ssh-keys

For about the last month, I have noticed excessive amounts (thousands per day) of jenkins-gitclient-ssh keys in the Keychain access app. These are for the tmp directory that Jenkins creates and it seems these get generated every time Jenkins polls the SCM for updates. Although I have no concrete proof of that. Its just a theory. Has anyone seen this before?

Example: SSH:/[project_path]@tmp/jenkins-gitclient-ssh#####.key

The following files are generated in the tmp directory but then are deleted within seconds.

jenkins-gitclient-pass#####.sh
jenkins-gitclient-phrase#####.txt
jenkins-gitclient-ssh#####.key
jenkins-gitclient-ssh#####.sh-copy
All of the numbers in these files are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the issue. I had created a Jenkins user (Manage Jenkins-> Manage Credentials) and used that for each of the build credentials. Setting the build credentials to "none" removed the @tmp directory and the SSH keys in the keychain.

Comment: I checked on this periodically over the last two weeks and have not seen any keys being generated. Problem solved.